# How can set data from Activity to Fragment after the Activity finish loading data

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fist off, I need to initial a series of Fragment classes;
after that, I do some NetWork Request;
after all the datas are loaded, I need to transport my specified data from Activity to Fragment, but I have no idea about this procedure.

the codes are as follows:

```
    private Class[] mFragmentClasses = {GoodDetailsFragment.class,GoodDetailsArgumentsFragment.class};
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);  
    mAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            return mFragmentClasses.length;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {  
            try {
                return (Fragment) mFragmentClasses[position].newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            return null;
        }  
    };  
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

so how could I update the datas which comes from Fragment as soon as the NetWork datas are loaded.

Comment: use `LocalBroadcastManager`.. that suits perfectly fine to your situation.

Answer (score 4):

Once the network request is complete and the Activity is done processing the data, it can use an `interface` to pass it to the fragment.

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public interface onDataLoadedListener
    {
        public void onDataLoaded(String receivedData);
    }

    onDataLoadedListener onDataLoadedListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        onDataLoadedListener = fragment;
    }

    // Some method called when you receive the data
    public void onDataReceived(String receivedData)
    {
        onDataLoadedListener.onDataLoaded(receivedData);
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements onDataLoadedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onDataLoaded(receivedData)
    {
        // Handle the received data accordingly
    }
}
```